# How to perform a non recursive copy using python

Tags: python, copy, shutil, non-recursive

I need to copy the files with certain patterns. I need to perform the non recursive copy on a given directory using shutil. I tried this code given below with performs recursive copy. Is there any options to specify in it to do the non recursive copy.

```
    from fnmatch import fnmatch, filter
    from os.path import isdir, join
    from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns

    src_directory = r'PATH'
    dst_directory = r'PATH'
    copytree(src_directory, ignored_directory,ignore=ignore_patterns('*.txt'))
```

Comment: What do you mean by non recursive? Only files from a directory or both files and directories but nothing under those directories?

Comment: only files from a directory not folders @ThatBird

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python copy files by wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371768/python-copy-files-by-wildcards)

Comment: Any solution in which you copy files by wildcards leaves out many nice features of copytree, such as symlink handling, copying the file metadata, etc. [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66941880/2394287) creates a truly non-recursive version of copytree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the destination directory exists first.
Then create a list of all the files to ignore with `glob.glob`. Then iterate over all the file and directories in the `src` directory and copy each file to the `dst` directory if it is a file and it is not in the `ignore` list:

```
import os, shutil, glob
src = 'my_dir'
dst = 'my_dir_cp'

try:
    os.mkdir(dst)
except FileExistsError:
    pass

ignore = glob.glob(os.path.join(src, '*.txt'))
for file in os.listdir(src):
    file = os.path.join(src, file)
    if file not in ignore and os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.copy(file, dst)
```

---

A full example:

```
$ ls my_dir
bob  cat.txt  fish  jim
$ python -q
>>> import os, shutil, glob
>>> src = 'my_dir'
>>> dst = 'my_dir_cp'
>>> 
>>> try:
...     os.mkdir(dst)
... except FileExistsError:
...     pass
... 
>>> ignore = glob.glob(os.path.join(src, '*.txt'))
>>> for file in os.listdir(src):
...     file = os.path.join(src, file)
...     if file not in ignore and os.path.isfile(file):
...         shutil.copy(file, dst)
... 
'my_dir_cp/jim'
'my_dir_cp/bob'
>>> 
$ ls my_dir_cp
bob  jim
```

---

If you want to be able to ignore multiple `glob` patterns, then you can `glob.glob` each of them and concatenate the results together (in a list-comprehension):

```
import os, shutil, glob
src = 'my_dir'
dst = 'my_dir_cp'

try:
    os.mkdir(dst)
except FileExistsError:
    pass

patterns_to_ignore = ['*.txt', '*.bat']
ignore = [e for p in patterns_to_ignore for e in glob.glob(os.path.join(src, p))]
for file in os.listdir(src):
    file = os.path.join(src, file)
    if file not in ignore and os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.copy(file, dst)
```

Comment: how to append multiple extension with ignore such as *.bat, *txt and etc @Joe Iddon

Comment: @Jarvis Ok, I will add, but please accept this answer then!

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a hack but will copy all the files in a directory to destination directory non recursively. You could use glob or regex to ignore files -

```
import re

def copytree(src, dst):
     for item in [f for f in os.listdir(src) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(src, f)) if not re.match(f, '[.]txt$')]:
         s = os.path.join(src, item)
         d = os.path.join(dst, item)
         shutil.copy2(s, d)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have chosen to use `copytree` from `shutil`, be aware that any solution in which you loop over the files to copy each one leaves out many nice features of `copytree`, such as symlink handling, copying the file metadata, etc.

You can keep all the extras by creating a non-recursive `copytree` called `copyfiles`. `copyfiles` works identically to `copytree`, except that it extends the `ignore` parameter to also ignore folders while copying.

```
import shutil, os

def copyfiles(src, dst, ignore=lambda a, b: set(), **kwargs):
    return shutil.copytree(src, dst, ignore=lambda s, names: set(ignore(s, names)).union(set(filter(lambda name: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(s, name)), names))), **kwargs)
```

```
# use copyfiles like so:

copyfiles(src_directory, dst_directory, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns('*.txt')) # copies non-recursively
```